# SVG script to fit artwork to bounds pre process

Tags: node.js, svg, automation, gruntjs

my current workflow is grabbing svg's from a server and doing some grunt tasks to get them into my webpage. My only issue at the minute is the svg's i'm grabbing don't tightly hug their artwork bounds, is there an automated way in which i can crop them to fit exactly in their bounds without doing it in illustrator directly? Preferably grunt/node related. I don't have access to the source svg's so doing it on them isn't an option.

**What i have**

[image: This is what i get]

**What i need**

[image: What i need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i created a node package with a grunt wrapper that does exactly what Bobby said, renders in phantom, gets bbox and sets the dimensions again, then saves the svg out, it's here if anyone else wants to use this.

https://github.com/mikemellor11/grunt-svgfit

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively simple svg like in your example, you could get the bounding box of the svg and then set the svg's width, height, and viewBox attributes based on the bounding box. For example, suppose you have the following svg...

```
<svg id="mySvg" height="200" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="black" stroke="none" d="M 40 20 L 160 100 L 40 180 L 20 160 L 120 100 L 20 40 Z"/>
</svg>
```

then you could use the following code...

```
var svg = document.getElementById("mySvg");
var bbox  = svg.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute("width", bbox.width);
svg.setAttribute("height", bbox.height);
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", bbox.x + " " + bbox.y + " " + bbox.width + " " + bbox.height);
```

Note that this approach has some limitations. The getBBox() method's returned value is exclusive of stroking, clipping, masking, and filtering. If your svg includes wide strokes or drop shadows (via filtering) then you would have to adjust the above code to add some extra space to the bounding box.

Comment: Hmm, i'm currently inserting the svg's using an external svg file and the <use> tag so im not currently setting width/height/viewbox on anything as all that is stored externally. I think i'm going to need to create a grunt module that loads the svg's in phantomjs or something and then does what you described above and then saves out another version.